# Number of terms in an Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Here is a question -

> The sum of the first four terms of an Arithmetic Sequence is 56. The
>   sum of the last four terms is 112. If its first term is 11, then find
>   the number of terms.

Here's what I have done so far -

To find the common difference, $d$ -

$\Rightarrow\;$ Sum = $\displaystyle \frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle \frac{4}{2}(2(11)+(4-1)d)=56$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle 22+3d=28$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle 3d=6$

$\displaystyle \therefore\ d=2$

Now to find the first term, $a_1$, of the last four terms -

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle \frac{4}{2}(2(a_1)+2(4-1))=112$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle 2a_1+6=56$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle 2a_1=50$

$\displaystyle \therefore\ a_1=25$

Then, to find the last term of the sequence -

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle a_4=a_1+3d$

$\Rightarrow\; \displaystyle a_4=25+3(2)$

$\displaystyle \therefore\ a_4=31$

Now I don't know what to do after this. Given the first term ($11$) and last term ($31$) of the sequence, how would you find the number of terms, $n$, in this sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding from what you've already done, write $a_1 = 11$ and $a_n=31$. You have the recurrence $a_r = a_{r-1}+2$ and so $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$.

The rest is just evaluating $31 = 11 + 2(n-1) \implies n = 11$

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are an odd number of terms (say $2n+1$)
Then, let the middle term be $a$

$(a-nd)+(a-(n-1)d)+(a-(n-2)d)+(a-(n-3)d)=56$

$(a+nd)+(a+(n-1)d)+(a+(n-2)d)+(a-(n-3)d)=112$

(add)

$8a=56+112=168\implies a=21$

Now, Subtract the equations

$2nd+2(n-1)d+2(n-2)d+2(n-3)d=112-56=56$

$8nd-12d=56\implies 2nd-3d=14\implies2nd=3d+14$

Also, $21-nd=11\implies nd=10$

So, $d=2$

$21-nd=11\implies n=5$

Number of terms $=2n+1=11$

EDIT: This method works even if there are an even number of terms. Simply let the number of terms be $2n+1$ where $n$ is a fraction, and $a$ is the average of the middle pair